# php output not displaying first item details and errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

[image]

Ok sorry to be annoying. I have two questions

1. Why am i getting the errors seen above.
2. I am adding items to a basket. **No item can be reserved more than once in one session.** Cart Item 1 and Cart Item 4 are the same item but when i add the first item to the basket. it does not show the $key $value which should be bookid: 1 but does how the information for the rest of the items as you can see above.

any questions please ask, any help will be greatly appreciated.

PHP & HTML

```
<?php
include 'header.php';

$bookInBasket = "";

if(isset($_POST['bid'])){
    $bid = $_POST['bid'];
    $wasFound = FALSE;
    $i = 0;
    if(!isset($_SESSION["basket_array"]) || count($_SESSION["basket_array"]) < 1) {
        $_SESSION["basket_array"] = array("bookid" => $bid);
    } else {
        foreach($_SESSION["basket_array"] as $each_item){
            $i++;
            while(list($key, $value) = each($each_item)){
                if($key == "bookid" && $value == $bid){
                    $bookInBasket = "Sorry. You can only reserve one of each book at one time.";
                    $wasFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if($wasFound==FALSE){
            array_push($_SESSION["basket_array"], array("bookid" => $bid));
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptybasket"){
    unset($_SESSION["basket_array"]);
}

$cartOutput ="";

if(!isset($_SESSION["basket_array"]) || count($_SESSION["basket_array"]) < 1){
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>You need to add Books to view them here.</h2>";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION["basket_array"] as $each_item){
        $i++;
        $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i </h2>";
        while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
            $cartOutput .= "$key : $value <br />";
        }
    }
}

?>

<div id="azcontent"> 
            <h1>Basket</h1>

<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
<br /><br />
<a href="basket.php?cmd=emptybasket">Empty Basket</a>
<div> <?php echo $bookInBasket ?> </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Session Output (dump)

```
array(4) { 
                 ["bookid"]=> string(1) "1" 

[0]=> array(1) { ["bookid"]=> string(1) "2" } 

[1]=> array(1) { ["bookid"]=> string(1) "3" } 

[2]=> array(1) { ["bookid"]=> string(1) "1" } 

}
```

Comment: So, you've already got session_start() in the header file, right? You should var_dump($_SESSION); to see what's happening there.

Comment: @larsAnders for the above example the output is:    
array(4) { ["bookid"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> array(1) { ["bookid"]=> string(1) "2" } [1]=> array(1) { ["bookid"]=> string(1) "3" } [2]=> array(1) { ["bookid"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: The array structure is the problem - where is that array getting generated? The first element should be an array, but it's just a key => value pair. Notice how the other elements are all indexed with numbers, except that first entry. It's being added to the basket_array array incorrectly somewhere.

Comment: @larsAnders all the code above is what happens on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening when you initialize the array vs. when you use array_push to add to it.  Each time you use array_push, it's adding a new element that is an indexed array. When you initialize the array here:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["basket_array"]) || count($_SESSION["basket_array"]) < 1) {
    $_SESSION["basket_array"] = array("bookid" => $bid);
} else {
```

it's simply adding a key-value pair, rather than an array with an index. You can fix this by changing that line to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["basket_array"]) || count($_SESSION["basket_array"]) < 1) {
    $_SESSION["basket_array"] = array( array("bookid" => $bid));
} else {
```

The rest of your code is built to handle an array of indexed arrays (mainly through the use of foreach statements), rather than a flatter array of key-value pairs.

Comment: hey lars thanks for commenting, i have already started the session in the header.php file.